# Stop Visual Studio from accessing Online Reference Sources when going to Definition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, editor, reference-source

When I do a "**Go To Definition**" for a type in the c# code editor, say IDisposable, Visual Studio opens the **Reference Source** for IDispoable in the Browser: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/idisposable.cs,1f55292c3174123d

How can I **stop Visual Studio from opening a browser?**

How can I tell VS to open IDisposable in the Object Browser?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does not do that by default.

I would guess that you installed an extension (like [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SchabseSLaks.Ref12)) that does it for you.  Uninstall the extension and VS should revert to its default behavior.

Another possibility is that you enabled a feature in Resharper that does a similar thing.

Comment: R# is not the cause. Checked all extensions, does not look like any of them could be the reason. I believe my configuration is wrong, but could not find any config that affects the behavior.

Comment: You could also try launching an [experimental instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166560.aspx), which will use fresh configuration and see if it still happens there.